# How do I push a Docker Image in Virtual Box to Google repository?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I have a virtualbox `development`:

```
$docker-machine ls

NAME          ACTIVE   DRIVER     STATE        URL             SWARM  DOCKER ERRORS
development    -     virtualbox  Running  tcp://*.*.*.*:****  v18.05.0-ce
```

Inside `development` I have this:

```
$docker images
REPOSITORY            TAG      IMAGE ID         CREATED         SIZE
busybox              latest   e1ddd7948a1c      1 day ago      1.16MB
pritam/play-docker   latest   34eb2664f14e      1 day ago      1.4GB
```

Now I want to push this image inside virtual box to google repository. How do I that?

Comment: you can use docker push command https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/push/. For your own registry you can use docker push yourregistry/image https://blog.docker.com/2013/07/how-to-use-your-own-registry/. And for google conatiner registry reference is https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling

Comment: @Fahri But that will push to the docker repo. How will I push to the google io? For that I will need to install google cloud console and how do I do that in the docker-machine?

Comment: you can still push docker [push/pull] gcr.io/{PROJECT_ID}/{image}:tag
for authentication you can check google container registry reference// so after you get google auth keys $docker login -u _json_key -p “$(cat key.json)” https://gcr.io . https://medium.com/google-cloud/using-googles-private-container-registry-with-docker-1b470cf3f50a

Comment: @ Pritam Let me know if the provided answer addresses your issue. If yes, I would recommend that @Fahri posts it as a valid answer to make it available for our community members and to collect his well-deserved points.

Comment: @Fahri Can you please post the comment as an answer so that I can accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use docker push command

```
docker push imageTagName
```

> http://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/push

For your own registry you can use

```
 docker push registry.example.com/image
```

> http://blog.docker.com/2013/07/how-to-use-your-own-registry.

And for google container registry reference:

> http://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling

```
docker [push/pull] gcr.io/{PROJECT_ID}/{image}:tag
```

for authentication you can check google container registry reference

> https://medium.com/google-cloud/using-googles-private-container-registry-with-docker-1b470cf3f50a

after you get google auth keys as json format (key.json)

```
docker login -u _json_key -p “$(cat key.json)”
```

after login success you can push your image

```
 docker push gcr.io/project_id/imageName:tag
```